# OMXCodec::start() hangs when waiting for EXECUTING state

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I follow the tutorial [Use Android Hardware Decoder with OMXCodec in NDK](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk) to use OMXCodec to decode H264 frames.
But the program hangs when calling OMXCodec::start().

I did a basic debugging. The cause seems be as the following:

the OMX state change message from OMXNodeInstance::onMessages() had failed to come to the OMXCodecObserver inside OMXCodec.
So OMXCodec was nerver notified that the OMX state was changed to EXECUTING and it eventually hanged when waiting for the EXECUTING state.

But the root cause was not found yet.

Anynone familiar with libstagefright can offer a help ? Much appreciated !